# Is setting the viewport every frame a good idea?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been reading through a couple of tutorials for OpenGL-ES 2.0, and I noticed they set the viewport (glViewport) each 60Hz frame.

Is it a good idea to do that or is that just done to simplify the examples?

Are there performance penalties if you do that?

This is for iOS currently but aims to be portable to other platforms.

Comment: The performance impact is negligible.  I wouldn't bother examining it further: `glViewport()` is a drop in the bucket compared to, say, `glDrawArrays()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid any kind of redundant calls as long as it's relatively easy to do. In the case of `glViewport()`, it should be easily possible to only call it when the size of the viewport actually changes, which is typically when the window is resized.

In reality, it's unlikely that it will make a measurable difference in this case. Setting the viewport is most likely fairly cheap, so it should not hurt to do it once per frame. And the driver might eliminate the redundant call anyway.

How expensive certain state changes are is highly platform dependent. It's possible that certain calls that you would expect to be very cheap could be surprisingly expensive on specific platforms. For example, some platforms do blending as part of the fragment shader, so changing blend state causes a shader change that can be much more expensive than you would expect.

There are partly philosophical discussions about whether drivers should check for redundant state changes. Some will argue that they should not, because the extra tests will have some negative performance impact on well written applications that avoid redundant calls. But there's often not much of a choice, because there are a lot of poorly written apps/games used as benchmarks, and detecting redundant calls in the driver can give substantial performance improvements on those.